# Julia exits when using Pardiso solver on Windows

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix, pardiso

I installed the Pardiso.jl with instructions on the package webpage. And when I run the test code, Julia just exited with the error message below. When I run from 568-574 it was not a problem. but when I try to use solve!() Julia just crushed. The link directs me to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch
I am not an expert with using external solver so would anyone kindly help me out?

The terminal process "julia.exe '-i', '--banner=no', '--project=C:\Users\catie.julia\environments\v1.6', 'c:\Users\catie.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.4.3\scripts\terminalserver\terminalserver.jl', '\.\pipe\vsc-jl-repl-f9a2393d-4e4d-42ec-9aa9-acb076d5bde1', '\.\pipe\vsc-jl-cr-4f79880d-c78a-44bc-858d-92cdce1af703', 'USE_REVISE=true', 'USE_PLOTPANE=true', 'USE_PROGRESS=true', 'DEBUG_MODE=false'" terminated with exit code: 3221226356.

[test code on Parsido package website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVfNR.png)

[error message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuShA.png)

Comment: Are you using MKL PARDISO or PARDISO 6.0? If MKL, did you have it already installed or did Julia install it for you when adding this package?

Comment: I am using PARDISO 6.0. Since you asked, I went back to the installation guide (https://github.com/JuliaSparse/Pardiso.jl/blob/master/README.md)  and realized "Pardiso.show_build_log()" also gives me an error message says no log file found. I doubled checked the previous steps and everything is set as the guide.